# Identify which capturing group was matched in the evaluated string using regex

Tags: excel, regex, vba, conditional-statements, capturing-group

Hallo I'm new with regular expressions and im getting a hard time figuring out how to get the group that was matched in the evaluated string using regex in VBA.

There are 4 or more different possibilities of words it can appear in the string followed by 1 or more digits:

- W-Point =
- WR/KE-Point=
- WNr-Point=
- SST_P-Nr =

One of this words appear just once in the string

**Evaluated string:**
"3:  CALL U(Base,EZSP,Nr1,Pr-nr=20,Offset=1,Path=2,**WNr-Point=20**,Pr=65,ON)"

**Regexpattern used:**
(?:(W-Point=)(\d*)|(SST_P-Nr=)(\d*)|(WR/KE-Point=)(\d*)|(WNr-Point=)(\d*))

So far everything works :[Example](https://regex101.com/r/N6UzU0/1)

**Problem:** Identify which word/digit pair was matched and get its group number. Right now im looping through the results and discarding the submatches that are empty. is there a better or efficient way to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me. What is the end goal you are trying to accomplish? Have you tried: `(W-Point=|SST_P-Nr=|WR\/KE-Point=|WNr-Point=)(\d*)`?

Comment: What you are doing will work.  Or, using text functions, you could extract the part of the Match up to the `=` sign; then do a lookup for the position.

Comment: If your only goal is to "Identify which word/digit pair was matched and get its group number" and if the data is too large and the resultant number of matches is too much to be looped through, then you can simply execute the regex for each single group at a time and you don't have to identify the group again with a loop. I mean say if you don't actually want the maches but count of matches of each group, then better don't loop and execute regex separately for each group.

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad that was helpfull, i just wanted to know which word is in the string so i can do some other things with my code depending on that word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim s As String
    s = "3: CALL U(Base,EZSP,Nr1,Pr-nr=20,Offset=1,Path=2,WNr-Point=20,Pr=65,ON)"
    
    Dim Regex As Object, m As Object
    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With Regex
      .Global = True
      .MultiLine = False
      .IgnoreCase = True
      .pattern = "(W-Point|WR/KE-Point|WNr-Point|SST_P-Nr)( *= *)(\d*)"
    End With

    If Regex.test(s) Then
        Set m = Regex.Execute(s)(0).submatches
        Debug.Print m(0), "'" & m(1) & "'", m(2)
    End If
End Sub
```

update : capture = and any spaces

Comment: That worked good Thanks. The only comment is that the = i need to keep it in the first capturing group, there are words that follow this pattern **abc = 4** , **abc=4** or **abc= 4** and it is necessary to keep the white spaces if there are when i replace the numbers.

Comment: @Eduardo Ok see update, use `m(0) & m(1)` if you want to capture equals too.